# Laravel session getting unset on each pageload

Tags: php, session, laravel

my session data is getting unset on each page load. I noticed it when I was trying to create a user log in area. Auth::attempt worked fine but on next page load the auth user data was gone.

I checked the session by setting a session after Auth::attempt and then then checked it in the auth filter but the session data was not there. This is my config/session.php content

```
 <?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => array(2, 100),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'lodgesdirect',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => 'test_path',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => false,

);
```

I have spent hours searching and changing the code but still the session is just getting

Please can anyone help on this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then i tried

```
Session::save();
```

after put / pushing data into session

**Edit**

My Problem was that everytime i tried to create my session and push data to it, it would return just fine. but if i refreshed the page it would just do the same action once again, without appending data to the session.

```
if(Session::has('mySession'))
{
    //Session exists because of the Session::save, lets push
    Session::push('mySession', 'World!');
}
else 
{
    Session::put('mySession', ['Hello']);
}

Session::save();
```

Comment: Thanks my team was hunting this since morning. This saved as hell lot of unknown amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem so I added session_start(); code in public/index.php at top. And my problem solved.

Comment: I experienced the same and this solved my problem as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions nor persisting is a common problem. It happens when you output some data before you actually save something into session. It does not output any error message, and is hard to debug. Mkae sure, you do not have any `echo`. `print()` or `headers()` related command  before `Auth::attempt()` or `Session::put()`.

One of the way how to solve it, is to use fresh Laravel installation. It takes time, but in many times it can resolve the mysterious issues like this.

Comment: Okay I will check if any data is output before saving session. Thank You for your time.